# Prevent stanza splitting in two column critical edition using `reledpar`

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I am making a critical edition using `eledmac` and `eledpar`.  The bulk of it is in verse, each verse having two lines.  There are also parallel texts, in columns.

What I want to do is to have none of the verses split between pages, so that the first line of a verse is on one page and the second on another.  For some reason `eledpar` makes it so that when I have two parallel texts in columns, the verses end up getting split, even if I use the `\setstanzapenalties` command.  For the MWE I used verses in six lines as this way it's easier to get a split verse.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}

\setstanzaindents{0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

\setstanzapenalties{1,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,10000,0}

\begin{pairs}

\begin{Leftside}

\beginnumbering

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of \edtext{verse.}{\Afootnote{Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text.}}\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of \edtext{verse.}{\Afootnote{Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text.}}&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of \edtext{verse.}{\Afootnote{Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text.}}&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\endnumbering

\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}

\beginnumbering

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of \edtext{verse.}{\Afootnote{Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text.}}\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of \edtext{verse.}{\Afootnote{Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text.}}&
Fifth line of \edtext{verse.}{\Afootnote{Apparatus text. Apparatus text.
 Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text.}}&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of \edtext{verse.}{\Afootnote{Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. Apparatus text. 
Apparatus text.}}&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\stanza
First line of verse.&
Second line of verse.&
Third line of verse.&
Fourth line of verse.&
Fifth line of verse.&
Sixth line of verse.\&

\endnumbering

\end{Rightside}

\end{pairs}

\Columns

\end{document}

Comment: unfortunately, this feature, many time asked, is not easy to implement in parallel typesetting. Try the option "nopbinverse", but I know it is buged for parallel pages. Open an issue with a buged MWE, but I can't say you when I could look on it.